# Java System.out.format() is not displaying when it is executed and output is getting delayed

Tags: java, amazon-s3

I am trying to a directory from 'Aws S3' using

```
MultipleFileDownload transfer = transferManager.downloadDirectory(bucketName,
                            prefix,
                            localFile,
                            true);
showTranferProgress(transfer);
```

and using [this code to print the progress of transfer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-s3-transfermanager.html#transfermanager-get-progress-polling) whose code is basically

```
 public static void showTransferProgress(Transfer xfer) {
        // print the transfer's human-readable description
        // System.out.print(xfer.getDescription() + "\t");
        System.out.format("%-80s\t", xfer.getDescription());
        // print an empty progress bar...
        printProgressBar(0.0);
        // update the progress bar while the xfer is ongoing.
        do {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(100);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            }
            // Note: so_far and total aren't used, they're just for
            // documentation purposes.
            TransferProgress progress = xfer.getProgress();
            double pct = progress.getPercentTransferred();
            eraseProgressBar();
            printProgressBar(pct);
        } while (xfer.isDone() == false);
        // print the final state of the transfer.
        TransferState xfer_state = xfer.getState();
        System.out.println(": " + xfer_state);
    }
```

Where `eraseProgressBar()` and `printProgressBar(int)` are basically a bunch of `System.out.print()` operation. 
Following is the code

```
    // prints a simple text progressbar: [#####     ]
    public static void printProgressBar(double pct) {
        // if bar_size changes, then change erase_bar (in eraseProgressBar) to
        // match.
        final int bar_size = 40;
        final String empty_bar = "                                        ";
        final String filled_bar = "########################################";
        int amt_full = (int) (bar_size * (pct / 100.0));
        System.out.format("  [%s%s]", filled_bar.substring(0, amt_full),
                empty_bar.substring(0, bar_size - amt_full));
    }

    // erases the progress bar.
    public static void eraseProgressBar() {
        // erase_bar is bar_size (from printProgressBar) + 4 chars.
        final String erase_bar = "\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b\b";
        System.out.format(erase_bar);
    }
```

The `TransferManager` is hopefully downloading the files in some another thread while updating the download progress and from the `Main` thread it is expected to print the progress using the above methods.

Now the strange part is, while debugging the `ShowTransferProgress()` method, I can clearly see the program executing `eraseProgressBar()` and `printProgressBar()`, precisely executing 
`System.out.format()`, but strangely nothing is displayed on the screen at atll.
And when the transfer is completed, entirely filled progress bar is printed on the screen, which basically destroys the requirement of progress bar at all.

I feel that the `System.out.format()` operations are getting delayed somehow and is executed at the end which is not something I need.

Why is it going on here? If they are getting delayed, why? And how to make them print as soon as they encounter a `format()` statement?

Comment: Try calling `System.out.flush()` after your calls to `System.out.format(...)`

Comment: Could it be that one of your calls is blocking? Maybe `xfer.getProgress()` doesn't return until everything is done for some reason?

Suggest you try the program with a regular `System.println(...)` first and see if that works as expected.

Comment: @Matthew I am sure the calls are non-blocking. If they were blocking, It won't make any sense. However, while debugging I made sure they are non-blocking. 
Also, I will try using `println()` and update.

Comment: @Sean Bright  @Matthew  I tried using `System.println(...)` and it prints as desired. I mean it prints when print statement is executed. However, this behaviour is not seen in `System.out.format()`. Also, `System.out.flush()` is not working. So, now the culprit here is `.format()`, we need to look closer why `.format()` is delaying output.